# Map individual images to the surface of a sphere

Tags: uv-mapping, scenekit

I know this is a FAQ but I don't know the terms to search on. I even saw something like this with a blue globe, but now I can't find it any more!

I'm trying to make a UV map to apply to a sphere (in SceneKit, so one big image).

The map is made up of multiple photos taken with the camera pointed in different directions. You could imagine taking a series of polaroids, putting a dot of glue in the center of each one, and then sticking it to the outside of a basketball. Compare and contrast with using paper mache, which would plaster the surface smoothly - in this case it's all bumps and gaps, but that's what I want.

It's easy enough to composite each image into a single 2D map. However, when you apply that to the sphere, all the formerly linear edges end up convex - barrel distortion. I need to transform each one (to be concave) before I composite them, so that when they are applied to the sphere they return to being rectangles as seen from the center.

So... assuming I have a collection of images, the FOV angle of the camera, and the alt/az orientation when they were taken, what's the trick for mapping them into a proper UV texture to recreate the "bumpy ball" with nice linear edges?

Comment: Could you simply use [gnomonic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnomonic_projection) from the camera's position? This will map straight lines in the image to straight lines in the camera's view, regardless of the position/orienation of the image around the sphere, camera FoV, or other variables.

Comment: I think what I want is the opposite of this? This is a mapping of the surface of a 3D object onto 2D. I already have 2D images.

Comment: Then apply it in reverse. The concept is the same, it's just a matter of which point you consider to be the input versus which you call the output.